# Which Android components and in which methods can rise Application Not Responding issue and why?

Tags: java, android, performance

It is meant for Services, Activities, Fragments and so on. Does it only occur in the case of some heavy operations in the UI thread?

Also just wondering - which method of those components can throw/rise ANR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Android, the system guards against applications that are insufficiently responsive for a period of time by displaying a dialog that says your app has stopped responding. At this point, your app has been unresponsive for a considerable period of time so the system offers the user an option to quit the app
>
> Generally, the system displays an ANR if an application cannot respond to user input. For example, if an application blocks on some I/O operation (frequently a network access) on the UI thread so the system can't process incoming user input events. Or perhaps the app spends too much time building an elaborate in-memory structure or computing the next move in a game on the UI thread. It's always important to make sure these computations are efficient, but even the most efficient code still takes time to run.
>
> In Android, application responsiveness is monitored by the Activity Manager and Window Manager system services. Android will display the ANR dialog for a particular application when it detects one of the following conditions:
>   No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
>   A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.

Picked out the parts which are relevant to your question.
But for more information, check out the [android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) where I got this from.

And ANR usually occurs when you are running long running operations (ex. networking) on the main thread.